# How to add strike through on Text in react native?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

Hey I want to add Strike Through in $10 amount for showing cut amount. Please check below :

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.inputWrapstotal}>
        <Text style={styles.labelcolor}>16.7% Off</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.inputWrapstotal}>
        <Text style={styles.labelamount}>Rs $10</Text>
        <Text style={styles.labelamountchange}> 12 </Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Please add css so that i can align in a line of both text , Thanks in Advance.

Please check the images [image]

Answer (score 162, accepted):

With :

```
<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through', textDecorationStyle: 'solid'}}>
  Solid line-through
</Text>
```

Answer (score 23):

```
<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'line-through' }}>Strike through text</Text>
```

You can find more text styling options from the official documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `textDecorationLine` with 'line-through' property like below:

```
<Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'line-through' }}>$12</Text>
```

it will put a line over your text!

Answer (score 5):

**So you want to achieve this right??**

[image]

```
<Text style={styles.oldPrice}>$19.19</Text>
```

just pass this style to the text component

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  oldPrice: {
    textDecorationLine: 'line-through',
    textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Text textDecorationLine="line-through" fontSize={12}>${price}</Text>
```